# Как вернуться к прежней версии вопроса в режиме изменения?

Tags: поддержка, правки, откат-правок

Если я понял, что прежний вариант кода в примере был правильным - как вернуть его? Я не вижу кнопок предыдущей версии в режиме правки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сообщение имеет несколько ревизий, то под сообщением (в обычном режиме просмотра) есть ссылка на это:

> [image: Изменён]

После открытия страницы ревизий на ревизиях кроме последней есть ссылка "откат":

> [image: Откат]